# Simple if statement not working properly

Tags: java, android, if-statement

```
    int sch = 1;

    if (sch == 1){
        Log.d("check", "1");
    }
    if (sch == 2){
        Log.d("check", "2");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("check", "error!");
    }
```

This is an extremely simple statement.

I am using exact same statement in my android java code,

And it shows `check: 1` in logcat as supposed.

And when i get to real code i am using,

```
    int sch = 1;

    if (sch == 1){
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));}

        Log.d("check", "1");
    }

    if (sch == 2){            
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));}

        Log.d("check", "2");
    }
    else {
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));}

        Log.d("check", "error");
    }
}
```

When i run this code, it should show `check: 1` on the logcat and show red on the status bar.

but it shows like this :

```
check: 1
check: error
```

And shows white on the status bar.

This is the exact code, and i didn't find anything wrong.

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: @commonswave answer is correct but you should really use a switch statement here.

Comment: Just read your simple if statement logically. "If it's 1, then do something. If it's 2, do something, otherwise do something else." That is not the same as "If it's 1, do something, *otherwise if it's 2*, do something else, otherwise, it's not 1 or 2, so do something else"

Comment: @BedrockDev Did you search on internet? This is really a simple problem.

Comment: i had another working code with 2 if statements and 1 else statements (without else if statement). So i thought there was no problem :(

Comment: @BedrockDev You should have searched on the internet, before asking this question in SO. By the way, welcome to SO.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question like this, but i searched the internet and found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) page but missed the else if statement.. ;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (sch == 2)
```

with:

```
else if (sch == 2)
```

As it stands, for `sch` of `1`, it will match `sch==1` of your first `if`, and the `else` condition of your second `if`. See [this official Java tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) for more details of how `else if` works.

Answer (score 2):

You need an if structure like the following, otherwise, if `sch == 1`, it will pass two test, the first one and the last one like in your question.

```
if (sch == 1){
    Log.d("check", "1");
} else if (sch == 2) {
    Log.d("check", "2");
} else {
    Log.d("check", "error !");
}
```

---

### Switch

Best solution when using multiple condition and a primitive integer is a `switch` statement like the following where the `default` is equivalent to your `else`

```
switch(sch){
    case 1 : Log.d("check", "1") : break;
    case 2 : Log.d("check", "2") : break;
    default : Log.d("check", "error !") : break;
}
```

Comment: @Bedrock Dev - and your if/else/if is equivalent  to leaving out case 2's break and falling through to the default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int sch = 1;

if (sch == 1){
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));}

    Log.d("check", "1");
}

else if (sch == 2){            
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));}

    Log.d("check", "2");
}
else {
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));}

    Log.d("check", "error");
}
}
```